# No signal on network cable

Tags: networking, cable, rj-45, cat6, cat5

I have two cat6 cables running through the house. On one side, the tech guy from my internet provider clipped cat5 jacks on the cable. On the other side I'm trying to install some wall socket.

I connected one of the cables but my computer found no signal at all.

So I bought a cable tester. Again, no signal at all.

Then I disconnected the wall socket and tried to hold one stripped wire into the cable tester directly. No signal.

Then I also cut off the cat5 jack on the other side, thinking perhaps that would be the problem. I then held one stripped wire into the cable tester directly (on both sides). No signal.

It is possible that both cables are broken, though I find it unlikely. Is it possible the cable tester doesn't work on distances greater than 10 meter or something? Or do cable testers only work when all the cables are plugged in?

Comment: Depends on the tester. Most that I have seen will test each wire individually as long as the main unit and the remote unit are on both ends of the cable. As for distance, they should put out enough power to test at least up to the "max" length for cat cables (100 meters).

Comment: My tester also goes through all the wires individually. So holding a wire on any copper connector on both sides of the tester should trigger some signal, is that correct? Then that only can mean both my cables are somehow broken?

Comment: It should. Do any of the wires test OK?

Comment: Mice love chewing on cables.

Comment: No, I get no signal at all from any wire.
@Moab: the cable is protected by a flexible plastic tube, and I would have probably heard if we had mice.

Comment: plastic tube won't stop them, was just a suggestion.